# calling subscribe on observable inside try catch block

Tags: rxjs, try-catch

Can someone explain to me why this is not getting caught by the catch block, I am thinking its because I have a switch map, which would unsubscribe from the first observable. Have commented it out with no luck. The first observable *(this.apiPaymentService.deleteStoredPaymentMethod()*) is the one causing a 403

```
try {
 this.apiPaymentService.deleteStoredPaymentMethod()
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.apiPaymentService.getStoredAchPaymentMethods(),
      catchError((err) => { return throwError(err)})
      ).subscribe()
 
} catch (error) {
  console.log('I am never called ')
  this.errorModal(error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First: Make sure your code parses

If I throw this into my IDE, I get a parsing error immediately. I'll assume you don't want an operator as a second parameter to switchMap and that you've simply forgotten an `)` near the end of the line.

#### What's happening inside your try block?

Inside your try block, you subscribe to an observable. That's it. That's what happens there. The subscription happens without an error. So your try-catch will complete without an error.

If `this.apiPaymentService.getStoredAchPaymentMethods()` is asyncronous, the try block will have completed (and may not even be on the call stack anymore) before `getStoredAchPaymentMethods()` resolves with a value.

#### How to manage Asynchronous Errors

You're already most of the way there! Instead of catching and then rethrowing an error, you can manage it right there.

The following is a no-op:

```ts
catchError((err) => { return throwError(err)})
```

But you can return something else instead, or you can retry or something like that :)

#### Aside: not just observables

Here's some old-skool code with the same underlying phenomenon.

```ts
function throwErrorFunction() {
  console.log("Throwing an error!");
  throw 'Throwing an error from my throw error function';
}

try {
  setTimeout(throwErrorFunction, 5000);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('I am never called ');
}
```

Here's a way to think about this. The code above never calls the `throwErrorFunction`. Function application in JavaScript is done wiht parenthesis. So you'd need something like `throwErrorFunction()` somewhere in order to call the function. But that never happens here.

But somehow the console will still read "Throwing an error!". So how does that happen if we've not called `throwErrorFunction`? Well... `setTimeout` eventually calls `throwErrorFunction` for us! In this case, it waits 5 seconds and then calls the function.

But by the time five seconds have elapsed, the try-catch statement has already been executed. Same deal as before! :)

Comment: so the code complies fine
the this.apiPaymentService.getStoredAchPaymentMethods() just called an HTTP endpoint

Comment: @SightSoundM Doesn't compile, `switchMap`doesn't take `catchError` as an argument. Regardless there are more opening parenthesis than closing ones, so it doesn't compile

Comment: Sorry yeah may have copied the code wrong but I can assure you it does compile